# How to make websocket ws:// server with api gateway+lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I can make wss:// server referring to the following site.

https://github.com/aws-samples/simple-websockets-chat-app

However, I want to make ws:// server because my client uses the protocol.
API gateway only shows a URL with wss://. How can I make ws:// server?